# how to dynamically log messages with different levels? eg: logging.x("message") where x in ['warn',error',..]

Tags: python, logging

I want to have a function `def log(message, level): logging.level("message")`, instead of writing `logging.error("message")`, I just want to call this function log("message",error). This is the code.

```
import logging

def logging_exception(message, level):

    raise Exception(message)

    logging.level(message)


logging_exception("this is an error",error)
```

expected result: `error message : this is an error`

Comment: Use an if, else chain?

Comment: I want something with just a line , without using if else for each level.I have multiple levels.

Comment: if you're going to have to type `log(message, error)` everytime then whats the difference between that and calling `log.error(message)`

Comment: it can be log(message,warning) too

Comment: `level = 'info', func = getattr(logging, level); func('hello world')`

Answer (score 2):

If you are happy to use the integer logging level definitions instead of the text ones (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging-levels) then you can use the log method instead of the individual level methods

```
import logging

logging.log(50,"This is a critical log message")
```

Output:

```
CRITICAL:root:This is a critical log message
```

Comment: +1 for using the builtin answer. you can also pass `logging.INFO`, `logging.ERROR`, `logging.WARNING`, etc. to this as well.

Comment: Great, glad to help. Please mark my post as your answer if it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

you could implement this in a fairly straightforward fashion by simply defining a `dict` that contains all the names you want to call, and then passing the value to the dict to retrieve your desired logging level.

```py
import logging
global __logger_methods
__logger_methods = {
    logging.DEBUG: logging.debug,
    "debug": logging.debug,
    logging.INFO: logging.info,
    "info": logging.info,
    logging.WARNING: logging.warning, 
    "warning": logging.warning,
    logging.WARN: logging.warn,
    "warn": logging.warn,
    logging.ERROR: logging.error,
    "error": logging.error,
    logging.CRITICAL: logging.critical,
    "critical": logging.critical
}

def logging_exception(message, level):
    global __logger_methods
    if level in __logger_methods.keys():
        __logger_methods[level](message)
    else:
        logging.error("Unknown Logging Level {} for message `{}`".format(level, message))
    raise Exception(message)


logging_exception("this is an error", logging.ERROR)
```

that last line produces the following output:

```
ERROR:root:this is an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File ".\__main__.py", line 24, in <module>
    logging_exception("this is an error", logging.ERROR)
  File ".\__main__.py", line 21, in logging_exception
    raise Exception(message)
Exception: this is an error
```

Comment: I mean, it's only ~25 lines... 13 of which are data definition. This is easy to read and understand, which is one of the more important aspects of code. All in all, this will likely be a very small portion of your application. Also, this does not have the `exec` issues that your implementation carries.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it this way, open to new ideas!

```
import logging
def logging_exception(message, level):

    str = 'logging.'+level+'('+"message"+')'    

    exec(str)

    raise Exception(message)   


logging_exception("this is an error",'error')
```

Comment: You should try to avoid the use of `exec` at all costs

Comment: it can be `logging.error(message);import virus;virus.run()`, too. that's why exec is so dangerous.

Comment: also, you may have inadvertently overwritten the `str` class here. you should name your variable something else.

Answer (score 0):

My final code is working like this. Thanks all the contributors.

import logging

def logging_exception(message, level):

```
level_code = getattr(logging,level.upper())

logger.log(level_code,message)

raise Exception(message)
```

logging_exception("error message",'error')